# Visual Studio 2013 NuGet package restore does not work from command line (not msbuild but vcvarsall.bat)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Visual Studio 2013 introduced *new* way of package restore without MSBuild and the old way of *Enable NuGet Package Restore* is [deprecated](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore) now.

After migrating a project, as written in [Nuget docs](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore),
when building in VisualStudio package restore works, but when build is run using command line VisulStudio and event **vcvarsall.bat** packages are not restored.

Am I missing something?

---

### Conclusion

Well, if you invoke Visual Studio from command line, package restore is not called. Use manual package restore with [**nuget.exe**](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore)

```
nuget restore Solution.sln
```

> For this particular line to work you'll need to install NuGet system wide and add path to it's binaries folder into `PATH` environment variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the commandline you must manually run `Nuget restore solution.sln` before invoking `msbuild.exe`. It's just a small step before the build runs.

Visual Studio does this automatically and the call to `nuget restore` is also executed by Team Build as part of the workflow.

Comment: You can also wrap up the nuget restore command line in an MSBuild project. See http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build

Comment: I am not manually invoking msbuild.exe, I'm invoking vcvarsall.bat which launches Visual Studio process, not msbuild.

Comment: @Kiliman: A very interesting decision to commit only .targets files from package folder, so that task imports would work. But I can't tell, if it won't have any negative impacts in future, so i'll probably stick with nuget restore.